# Office web app - Remove buttons

Tags: ms-office, office-web-components

Is there any way to remove buttons or complete ribbons from Office web apps. I want to remove Download, Add to one drive etc.

Sample url is below

https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=www.cse.lehigh.edu%2F~glennb%2Foose%2Fppt%2FCsharp_dotNET.ppt

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the appropriate css files to:
.Class or #ID etc.
display: none;

Word can be found in: 
"[drive here]:\microsoftwebapps\WebOneNote\Resources\1033\WordEditor.css"

Excel can be found in: 
"[drive here]:\microsoftwebapps\ExcelServicesWfe_layouts\styles\excelribbon.css"

PowerPoint can be found in: 
"[drive here]:\microsoftwebapps\WebPPTViewer\pptresources\1033\stylesEdit.css"

I used IE's DOM explorer to target specific classes & IDs of the buttons I wanted to remove.

Good luck, it is a huge pain in the a**

An example would be

"#btnOpenInClient{display:none;}"

This is my first answer. I didn't really have time to format, but it should help. I literally jsut did this for my OWAs

Comment: FireFox is really good for getting the css unique identifier for the ribbon/ buttons

Answer (score 0):

There's no other helpful way to say this other than "no, it's not possible". Only the client Office Applications allow UI customizations, but those are limited to hiding or disabling Ribbon components.

Answer (score 0):

The bellow powershell script should serve the purpose:
Please adjust $hideElements array accordingly to your purpose.

Add custom css to hide multiple options in File menu (Info, Save as, Print, Share, Exit)
  OWA CSS files that will be modified:  WordEditor.css, WordViewer.css, stylesEdit.css, stylesRead.css, ExcelFrame.css

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$action
)
$action = $action.ToLower()
$acceptedActions = "apply","rollback"

if ($acceptedActions -notcontains $action) {
    throw "Invalid action. Accepted actions: apply,rollback"
}

$owaPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Web Apps"

$hideElements = "#_x{} a[id$=Save-Menu32]{display:none;} a[id$=SaveAs-Menu32]{display:none;} a[id$=Print-Menu32]{display:none;} a[id$=Share-Menu32]{display:none;} a[id$=Close-Menu32]{display:none;} #btnOpenInClient-Medium{display:none;} #btnFileSharing-Medium{display:none;}";

$cssFiles =  "$owaPath\WebOneNote\Resources\1033\WordEditor.css", "$owaPath\WebPPTViewer\pptresources\1033\stylesEdit.css", "$owaPath\WebWordViewer\Resources\1033\WordViewer.css", "$owaPath\WebPPTViewer\pptresources\1033\stylesRead.css", $owaPath\ExcelServicesWfe\_layouts\1033\styles\ExcelFrame.css"

function ApplyPatch($cssFile, $hideElements) {
    if(-Not (Get-Content $cssFile).Contains($hideElements)) {
        $cssBackupFile = "$cssFile.bak"
        Copy-Item -Path $cssFile -Destination $cssBackupFile -Force
        Add-Content $cssFile $hideElements
        Write-Host "Patch applied on $cssFile"
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Patch already applied on $cssFile."
    }
}

function RollbackPatch($cssFile, $hideElements) {
    $cssBackupFile = "$cssFile.bak"
    if((Test-Path $cssBackupFile) -eq 1) {
       Copy-Item -Path $cssBackupFile -Destination $cssFile -Force
       Remove-Item $cssBackupFile
       Write-Host "Rollback applied on $cssFile"
    } else {
       Write-Warning "Missing backup file for $cssFile. Cannot rollback"
    }
}

If($action -eq "apply") {
    foreach ($cssFile in $cssFiles) {
        ApplyPatch $cssFile $hideElements
    }
}

If($action -eq "rollback") {
    foreach ($cssFile in $cssFiles) {
        RollbackPatch $cssFile $hideElements
    }
}
```