# How to disable download PPT option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I am using ReactJS in my project and I want to remove a 'download' option from the `iframe` tag.

I am using an `iframe` tag to view a Powerpoint PPT file:

```
<iframe src={'https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=' + this.state.presentationhtml} title="presentation"style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px" }} frameborder='0'allowFullScreen{true}></iframe>
```

Can anyone suggest me any other React component where we can view a PPT without a 'download' option or any other solution in which by using an `iframe` I can hide the download option?

Comment: The download option is coming from the powerpoint viewer in office apps. You cannot amend that. To do what you require you'd need to host your own powerpoint viewer whose display options you can control.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Office web app - Remove buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268096/office-web-app-remove-buttons)